# Give an example function $f \in L_p(\mathbb {R}) \forall \: p > 7,$ but $f \notin L_p(\mathbb {R}) \: p \leq 7$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Give an example function

$f \in L_p(\mathbb {R}) \forall \:  p > 7,$ but $f \notin L_p(\mathbb {R}) \:  p \leq 7$

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider $$f_q(x) = \begin{cases} x^{-q} & \text{ if }\,\,\, |x|>1\\
0 & \text{ else}\end{cases}$$

For which values of $p$ and $q$ is this in $L^p$?

Comment: If you look at a simpler example then
$\begin{equation*}
f(x) = 
 \begin{cases}
   x^\frac{-1}{7} \: |x|< 1, x \neq 0 \\
  0, else 
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$
it for $f \in L_{5}, but f \notin L_{7} $ and 
$\begin{equation*}
f(x) = 
 \begin{cases}
   x^\frac{-1}{5} \: |x|> 1 \\
  0, else 
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$
it for $f \in L_{7}, but f \notin L_{5} $